# For erc20, do transfer events need to match the exact amount subtracted from account _from and added to account _to?

Tags: solidity, erc20

Say for example, I wanted to burn half of every transaction that occurred. Heres some code (with no error checking or accounting for division rounding):

```
function transfer(address _to, uint _value) public override returns (bool success) {
        __balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;
        
        burn(_value / 2)

        __balanceOf[_to] += _value / 2;

        emit Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
        return true;
}
```

Is it correct to still emit the initial _value with the Transfer event? Or should 2 separate Transfers be emitted, one to the _to address with _value/2, and another to the 0x00000000 burn address with _value/2?

Answer (score 0):

There is no exact definition of `burn` in [EIP20](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-20). In fact, `burn`ing is just `transfer` to the zero address.

Your burn function should already emit `Transfer` event to the zero address.

```
function burn(uint256 _value) public {
    /* 
     ...
    */
    emit Transfer(msg.sender, address(0), _value)
}
```

Or, emit the same event in your transfer function (uglier)

### Edit 1

If what you want is to log that `_to` was received the total amount, I would not abuse the usage of a generic event such as `Transfer`, but use a second event. This would cost you just a little bit more gas but it is easier to search, maintain and read by third parties.

Comment: For clarity, what I was more focused on is: Is it bad to emit a Transfer(_from, _to, _value) event where _value is not the value that was received by _to?

Comment: well, if I were you, I would use transfer event as described above. half to address(0), other half to `_to`. And use another event such as `ValueTransferred` and emit it with the full value